# Opengl - Postprocessing multiple FBOs - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, lwjgl, fbo

I'm pretty new to OpenGL. I thought I understood FBOs, but I have trouble making them work.

My program draws to multisampled fbo basic graphical information (colorFbo).
From colorFbo I blit to postprocessFbo.
Then there's counterFbo with unsigned int values, where I simply fill silhouette of each object with object's id.

I'd like to postprocess the postprocessFbo and counterFbo, however, I don't see any effect of counterFbo... Where's the problem, please?
Here are parts my code:

Initialization:

```
colorFbo = new Framebuffer(true, false);   //multisampled, rgba
counterFbo = new Framebuffer(false, true); //not MS, red

...seting polygonmode, viewport, depthtest, blending...   

modelProgram = loadProgram("model");
counterProgram = loadProgram("counter");
...
postprocessProgram = loadProgram("postprocess");
...        
postprocessFbo = new Framebuffer(false, false); //not MS, rgba
```

Render loop:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, colorBuffer.fbo());
Main.clear(0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);        
drawing objects using model program...

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, counterBuffer.fbo());
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);        
drawing objects using counter program...

blit colorFbo to postprocessFbo...

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glUseProgram(postprocessProgram);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, postprocessFbo.fboColorTexture());
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, counterFbo.fboColorTexture());

glBindVertexArray(screenQuadArray);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Counter fragment shader:

```
#version 330

out uint counter;

in vec3 vPosition;

uniform uint id;

void main() {
    counter = id;
}
```

Postprocess fragment shader:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D colorTex;
uniform usampler2D counterTex;

out vec4 finalColor;

in vec2 texCoord;

void main() {
    finalColor = texture(colorTex, vec2(tex));
    uint id = texture(counterTex, vec2(tex)).s;
    if (id > 0) {
        finalColor = black;
    }
}
```

Framebuffer constructor:

```
public Framebuffer(boolean multisampled, boolean redOnly) {
    int internalFormat = redOnly ? GL_R32UI : GL_RGBA;
    int format = redOnly ? GL_RED_INTEGER : GL_RGBA;
    int dataType = redOnly ? GL_UNSIGNED_INT : GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    int interpolation = redOnly ? GL_NEAREST : GL_LINEAR;

    int textureType = multisampled ? GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE : GL_TEXTURE_2D;
    // Prepare FBO textures
    fboColorTexture = glGenTextures();
    fboDepthStencilTexture = glGenTextures();
    if (multisampled) {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, fboColorTexture);
        glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, SAMPLES, internalFormat, Main.width(), Main.height(), false);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, fboDepthStencilTexture);
        glTexImage2DMultisample(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, SAMPLES, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, Main.width(), Main.height(), false);            
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_MULTISAMPLE, 0);
    } else {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboColorTexture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, internalFormat, Main.width(), Main.height(), 0, format, dataType, (float[]) null);            
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, interpolation);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, interpolation);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fboDepthStencilTexture);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, Main.width(), Main.height(), 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8, (float[]) null);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }        

    fbo = glGenFramebuffers();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, textureType, fboColorTexture, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, textureType, fboDepthStencilTexture, 0);
    glDrawBuffers(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    int status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        System.err.println("Framebuffer not complete.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

Comment: I deleted it by mistake when I was writing the question, it's ok in the original code.sorry for mystifying.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing assigning the texture unit to the texture name. So when I load textures I normally do this in the initialization ...

```
uColorTex = glGetUniformLocation(shaders.shaderProgram, "colorTex");
uCounterTex = glGetUniformLocation(shaders.shaderProgram, "counterTex");
```

... and when drawing ...

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, postprocessFbo.fboColorTexture());
glUniform1i(uColourTex, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, counterFbo.fboColorTexture());
glUniform1i(uCounterTex, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, I do the first part in initialization (the three dots), I skipped that part because I felt I already felt I'm showing too much code.

Comment: Actually both parts, sorry for confusion. Keep in mind the colorTex works just fine, it's just the counterTex I can't get to work.

Comment: Including the glUniform1i bit ? Just asking because I got your code running fine, only that was missing

Comment: I do it in the initialization part, I tried moving it to rendering too and nothing changed. 
I see the objects from postprocessFbo, but they should be all black thanks to counterFbo, and they aren't...

Comment: Hum, try swapping the texture units around, so counter texture is GL_TEXTURE0

Comment: Still the same, color is ok, counter is not. It seems like I do something wrong with creating or switching the buffer, but I don't see anything. I even tried vec4 counter instead of unsigned int, still didn't work.

Comment: I tried the fbo code and it worked fine. Its like your counter isnt drawing to the fbo.

Comment: Another thing to try is set cou ter to 1 in the counter shader instead of id

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in counter program itself (in `glVertexAttribPointer`), which I didn't write about.
I needed only position in the counter program, so I wrote this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, FLOAT_VEC3_SIZE, 0);
```

But I forgot, that the data is always in the same position, so I can't "save space", because I'm only binding, the vertex data stays the same:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, SIZEOF_MODEL_VERTEX, 0);
```

Thanks for the answers, and sorry I didn't show more code, I thought the issue could be anywhere and didn't want to overwhelm anyone reading with too much code.

Comment: You didn't show this part of the code in the question. So it was impossible to answer the question.